# Converting a MATLAB code for generating 2D Laplacian matrix using a Kronecker product to python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, pde, laplacian

The following MATLAB code generates the 2D Laplacian matrix using a Kronecker product
approach.

```
function A=A(N)

% Assemble the system matrix A
e = ones(N,1);
D = spdiags([e -2*e e], -1:1, N, N);
I = speye(N);
A = kron(D,I)+kron(I,D);
h = 1/(N+1);
A=A/h^2;
```

`

I need to convert it to python in order to solve a PDE boundary value problem.

My first attempt involved using [SMOP](https://github.com/victorlei/smop#:%7E:text=SMOP%20is%20Small%20Matlab%20and,to%20be%20faster%20than%20octave.). Ran into a heap of errors and decided it wasn't worth the trouble.

My second attempt involved converting the code directly to python by using the [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/) and [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/) libraries.

Here's my attempt so far

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps


def build_laplacian_2D_kron(N):
    e = np.ones(shape=(N, 1))
    data = np.concatenate([e, -2*e, e] , axis= -1)
    diags = np.array([-1, 0, 1])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    D = sps.spdiags(data.transpose(), diags, N, N)
    I = sps.speye(N)
    A = np.kron(D, I) + np.kron(I, D)
    h = 1 / (N + 1)
    A = A / h ** 2
    A = sps.spmatrix.tocsc(A)

    return A


if __name__ == '__main__':
    build_laplacian_2D_kron(6)
```

When I attempt to run the code the following error shows up

```
ValueError: offsets array must have rank 1
```

The error is raised by the function [scipy.sparse.spdiags](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.spdiags.html) when invoking sps.spdiags on line 9. I presume that the issue is mainly with the way I am initializing data and diags. I have been trying to fix it for quite some time now but to no avail.

Any help would be highly appreciated

**Update**: With the recommendations from [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) I fixed the errors in the python implementation and updated the code above. Here's the output for `N = 2`

```
  (0, 0)    -36.0
  (1, 0)    9.0
  (2, 0)    9.0
  (3, 0)    0.0
  (0, 1)    9.0
  (1, 1)    -36.0
  (2, 1)    0.0
  (3, 1)    9.0
  (0, 2)    9.0
  (1, 2)    0.0
  (2, 2)    -36.0
  (3, 2)    9.0
  (0, 3)    0.0
  (1, 3)    9.0
  (2, 3)    9.0
  (3, 3)    -36.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However it does not quite match with the output in matlab(which excludes the 0 entries in the resulting matrix)

```
ans =

   (1,1)      -36
   (2,1)        9
   (3,1)        9
   (1,2)        9
   (2,2)      -36
   (4,2)        9
   (1,3)        9
   (3,3)      -36
   (4,3)        9
   (2,4)        9
   (3,4)        9
   (4,4)      -36
```

What modification can I make to my python implementation to exclude the 0 entries in my output? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your matlab code runs fine in Octave.

Comment: Why did you reshape `diags` to (1,3)?

Comment: Without reshaping diags, the code throws a `ValueError : number of diagonals (6) does not match the number of offsets (3)`

Comment: Use `sparse.kron`, not `np.kron` with sparse matrices.  Compared to the Octave I get a matrix with the same sparsity, but the values are different.  I haven't traced that.

Comment: How's a reshape to (1,3) supposed to help that?  The number of offsets remains 3, and it is no longer 1d!  You just replaced one error with another.  You didn't understand the original error.  The number of offsets has to match the number of rows in `data`.  One offset per row!  With `N` equals 3, it runs (without the rehape).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. How can I generalise my python code to work for any `N`?

Comment: In MATLAB `[e -2*e e]` makes a (N,3) matrix, with the 3 corresponding to the 3 offsets in `-1:1`.  In `sparse` you need `(3,N)` data to work with the `[-1,0,1]` offsets.